# Complex link between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. One first is my reference

```
df_ref
ID  REF  VALUE
A   1    12
A   2    36
A   3    95
B   1    54
B   2    67
B   3    81
C   1    89
C   2    123
C   3    14
```

And the second is my restricted :

```
df_restrict
ID  V1  V2
A   1   2
B   3   2
C   2   1
```

What I want is to replace V1 and V2 in `df_restrict` by the values corresponding to the `(ID, REF)` from `df_ref`

```
df_restrict
ID  V1  V2
A   12  36
B   81  67
C   123 89
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

We can pivot `df_ref` to reshape, then set the index of `df_restrict` to `ID`, then transpose and replace the the values from the reshaped `df_ref`

```
r = df_ref.pivot('REF', 'ID', 'VALUE')
df_restrict.set_index('ID').T.replace(r).T
```

---

```
     V1  V2
ID         
A    12  36
B    81  67
C   123  89
```

Answer (score 3):

`melt` the second DataFrame so you can `merge` the values on both columns, `['ID', 'REF']`, and then `pivot` back to your original shape.

```
df1 = (df_restrict.melt(id_vars=['ID'], value_name='REF')
        .merge(df_ref, how='left')
        .pivot(index='ID', columns='variable', values='VALUE')
        .rename_axis(columns=None))

#     V1  V2
#ID         
#A    12  36
#B    81  67
#C   123  89
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
df_restrict['V1']=df_restrict.merge(df_ref, left_on=['ID', 'V1'], right_on=['ID', 'REF'])['VALUE']

df_restrict['V2']=df_restrict.merge(df_ref, left_on=['ID', 'V2'], right_on=['ID', 'REF'])['VALUE']

>>> print(df_restrict)
  ID   V1  V2
0  A   12  36
1  B   81  67
2  C  123  89
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something

```
out = df_restrict.set_index('ID').T.replace(df_ref.pivot(*df_ref.columns).T).T
Out[188]: 
     V1  V2
ID         
A    12  36
B    81  67
C   123  89
```